# Proving a set is closed in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Given the subset 
>   $$
> F=\left\{f \in C[0,1]: \int_0^1 f(t)dt=1\right\}
> $$
>   show that $F$ is closed in $C[0,1]$ with the supremum metric.

Definitions we use:

*Limit point*: $x$ is a limit point of $F$ if each open ball centered at $x$ contains at least one point of $F$ different from $x$, i.e. $S(x,r)-\{x\}$ intersects $F$.

*Closed*: a subset $F$ of a metric space is closed if it contains each of its limit points.

My brain is completely frozen on this question, and my apologies for the poor form of my entries this is my first time posting. Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the sequential characterization of closed sets? That is, a subset $F$ of a metric space $X$ is closed if and only if every time a sequence $f_n$ of elements of $F$ converges, its limit is an element of $F$ itself.

Comment: Yes we have talked about this using what we call the "derived set" of F or the set of all limit points of F =F'. We say F is closed if F' is a subset of F.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this here is more a job for something else, there is a definition of continuousity that states, a function is continuous when preimages of closed sets are closed. This fact is more likely to help us how you will see.

Integration is a bounded linear operator and hence continuous. Your set is the Preimage of $\{1\}$ of the integral function. What do you know about the preimage of closed sets of continuous functions?

To make it more explicit define 
\[h(f)= \int_0^1 f(x) \; \mathrm{d}x\]
As \[\|h(f)\| \leq \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(x)| \]
and $h(\alpha f + \beta g)=\alpha h(f) +\beta h(g)$ we see $h$ is a linear and bounded operator, hence $h$ is continuous. As preimages of closed sets are closed and 
\[ F=h^{-1} ( \{ 1 \} )\]

Another proof of the continuousity of the Integral.

As we know the fundamental theorem of calculus   \[ \int_x^{x+h} f(s) \; \mathrm{d}s =h \cdot f(\xi) \] 
with $\xi \in (x,x+h)$ we gonna prove the Lipschitzcontinuouity of the Integral:

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_0^1 f(s)\; \mathrm{d}s - \int_0^1 g(s) \; \mathrm{d}s \right|&= 
\left| \int_0^1 f(s)-g(s) \; \mathrm{d}s \right|\\
&= \left| f(\xi)-g(\xi) \right| \leq \sup_{\xi \in [0,1]} |f(\xi)-g(\xi)|\\
&=1 \cdot \| f-g\| 
\end{align*}

So we have shown that 
$$ \|h(f)-h(g)\|_{2} \leq L \cdot \|f-g\|_{\text{sup}} $$

Comment: I don't think this is the solution the examiner is expecting. In a first course in metric spaces the concept of "bounded linear functional" is unlikely to be seen (IMHO).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I saw bounded linear functionals in my first year in university (I am now in my second) but never the less, as I proved that it is bouned, i proved it is Lipschitz continuous, so there is no problem or ?

Comment: Of course there is no problem for me, meaning that your solution is correct. You might want to expand a little on the continuity of the operator $f\mapsto \int_0^1 f\, dt$, if you have some spare time and if the OP requests so.

Comment: We haven't talked about bounded linear functionals yet and I think the answer here is very simple I just can't see it. There should be a way to show that every limit point of the set F is contained in C[0,1] hence showing that F is closed in C[0,1].

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I expanded the continuity, is it better now ?

Comment: @br549er9 what you don't unterstand ?

Comment: This makes sense but the simple part I am missing is how this shows all limit points f of the set F lie in C[0,1].

Comment: @br549er9 I don't work over limit points. I just show that the set is closed with an equivalent method, which implies it does have all limit points

Comment: Actually I see that now Dominic thank you so much!

Comment: @br549er9 When it helps you, you can accept it and upvote it :)

Comment: I don't understand why you are resorting to the mean value theorem (i.e. the formula $\int_x^{x+h}f(x)\, dx=f(\xi)h$) while in the rest of your text you claim that continuity of the functional is a consequence of the triangle inequality $$\left\lvert\int_0^1f(x)\, dx\right\rvert\le \lVert f \rVert_\infty.$$ It is not formally incorrect but it just feels wrong.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  oh i used it with $h=1$ maybe that is not that clear

Comment: No, it is clear. What I mean is that the mean value theorem is unnecessary: you could just use the triangle inequality and show that 
$$\left\lvert \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx - \int_0^1 g(x)\, dx\right\rvert\le \lVert f-g\rVert_\infty.$$
This is what you implicitly do when you claim that a bounded linear functional is continuous.